# ng-repeat with limitTo animates backwards when limit goes down

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-filters

This [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/wamumosoba/2/edit) shows what I'm trying to do.

The issue I'm having is that when using the `limitTo` filter with `ng-repeat`. When the limitTo variable is set to a higher value they animate in order top down, however when it's changed to a lower number, they still animate top down as opposed to bottom up.

How can I fix this behaviour is my only option to do custom removal and adding with a second array?

Comment: And the problem is ...? Do you want the animation bottom-up? Does it make a difference? Please don't assume that everyone visiting SO can also access jsbin.

Comment: Edited to be more clear sorry for any confusion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the limitTo with a negative number.

So if you want to see the bottom 3 you `limitTo -3`